# How to use Failed Request Tracing for HTTP status 200 for MVC app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 website hosted on Azure Websites that I'm trying to debug why it's starting very slowly. I want to use Failed Request Tracing but can't figure out how to setup the web.config to traced on status 200. I found this screencast [Failed Request Tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onemicrosoftvoice/archive/2012/12/27/screencast-troubleshooting-slow-requests-with-failed-request-tracing.aspx) which describes how to do it for .aspx files but I'm not sure what to set the path as for MVC controller actions. Here's the web.config settings from the screencast:

```
<!-- Tracing slow requests using Failed Request Tracing. -->
<tracing>
    <traceFailedRequests>
        <remove path="*" />
        <add path="*.aspx">
            <traceAreas>
                <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache, 
                                                                             RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI" verbosity="Verbose" />
            </traceAreas>
            <failureDefinitions statusCodes="200-999" />
        </add>
    </traceFailedRequests>
</tracing>
```

Any thoughts on how to set this up would be appreciated.

Jason

Comment: off-topic, but Azure websites sleep. Have you tried using the 'Always On' option to keep it warm and responsive?

Comment: Neil - I hadn't actually tried that but it looks like whatever the issue was has sorted itself out over the weekend. Thanks for the info though, I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the original problem has magically gone away but I think I know how to enable Failed Request Tracing for MVC apps. It looks like you just enable it for all paths:

```
<add path="*">
```

I probably should have tried that first.
Jason